# How to get a count of objects in All libraries in IBM i (AS/400) System using DB2

Tags: ibm-midrange

How get a total count of the number of objects in All libraries on a IBM i (AS/400) System. Is there a DB2 sql query for that

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Here at SO we are a community trying to help each other. Please have a look at the "How do I ask a good question" (stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to better frame your question, and consider looking at the "Minimal, Reproducible Example" section as well (stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you provide some code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: No there isn't an SQL Query for that and this doesn't appear to be programming related.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (IBMi 7.1 or higher):

```sql
select objlib, count(*)
from table (QSYS2.OBJECT_STATISTICS('*ALL', '*ALL') )
group by objlib
```

More info at [OBJECT_STATISTICS](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.4?topic=services-object-statistics-table-function).

Comment: I don't see `OBJLIB` at v7.2, but the link states that many new fields were added at v7.3. If you don't see `OBJLIB` on your box, you should be able to use `OBJLONGSCHEMA`. This is a **LONG** running query.